# How to search a string which length is 0 in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My documents have a keyword which value is "", how can I search it by java Elasticsearch?

No effect like the code is :

```
query.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("paymentRetCode", ""))
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `script` query in order to check that the length of the string is 0:

```
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "myscript", "doc.paymentRetCode.value.length() == 0", new HashMap())
query.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(script))))
);
```

Script queries are not ideal, though, you should set `null` instead of the empty string if you need to detect documents with empty strings, in which case you'll be able to use a negated `exists` query:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("paymentRetCode"))
```